# Filter array of objects with another objects as parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filtering

I would like to filter JSON data property name for each country for 'search' on website

```
let array = {
    continents: [
    {
      name: "Europe",
      countries: [
        {
          name: "Austria",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        },
        {
          name: "Germany",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Asia",
      countries: [
        {
          name: "Thailand",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        },
        {
          name: "Japan",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Expected behavior is when I type "an" The results will be an array like that:

```
let array = {
    continents: [
    {
      name: "Europe",
      countries: [
        {
          name: "Germany",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Asia",
      countries: [
        {
          name: "Thailand",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        },
        {
          name: "Japan",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

so we would get rid of Austria

How to achieve this? Should we use fliter function (benchmarks show that it is slow based on: https://jsperf.com/function-loops/11). Also can we also search in continent Name

Right now I know how to log the correct values out, but how to compose a correct array from them?

```js
let array = {
  continents: [
    {
      name: "Europe",
      countries: [
        {
          name: "Austria",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        },
        {
          name: "Germany",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Asia",
      countries: [
        {
          name: "Thailand",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        },
        {
          name: "Japan",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

searchValue = "an";

for (let i = 0; i < array.continents.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array.continents[i].countries.length; j++) {
    if (
      array.continents[i].countries[j].name
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      console.log(array.continents[i].countries[j].name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so far if you want debugging help. Speed is rarely a significant concern; you might first get something that *works* and then think about ways to make it faster.

Comment: _Should we use fliter function (benchmarks show that it is slow)_ proof please

Comment: `JSON` is not a great choice for a variable name.

Comment: @CertainPerformance poor snippet added

Comment: @baao I've included link I found at this topic

Comment: @CrazyTrain was just for showcase, I've edited it, thanks!

Comment: Regarding the benchmark, unless you have a massive list of tens or hundreds of thousands of items, you won't see a difference. Also, it's just as fast in Firefox, though it is a bit slower in Chrome. I still would't let that dictate the solution you choose. Just because it's "slower" than something else doesn't mean it's "slow".

Comment: @rsm I'm filtering out all countries which doesn't include "an" both Thailand and Japan have it

Answer (score 0):

well .. create an empty array and push the country name whenever it meets the criteria of the search :

```js
const array = {
  continents: [{
      name: "Europe",
      countries: [{
          name: "Austria",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        },
        {
          name: "Germany",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Asia",
      countries: [{
          name: "Thailand",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        },
        {
          name: "Japan",
          adresses: {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const searchValue = "an"
let result = []

array.continents.forEach(e =>
  e.countries.forEach(v =>
    v.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue) && result.push(v.name))
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This way I will loss the continents array